# Adding shipping via advanced variables or html code to paypal subscription button

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-buttons

I run a small localised oatmilk making and delivery business, and we are trying to set up a subscription model via paypal. The subscription buttons and reports give us (almost!) everything we need, however there is one snag - I don't seem to able to add a shipping / delivery amount at the checkout. I would like this to be separate from the main price so the price of the product itself is evident. Here is the code below - the only thing I've changed is the hosted button ID value:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XYZ">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="How many would you like?">How many would you like?</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="1">1 : £2.20 GBP - weekly</option>
    <option value="2">2 : £4.20 GBP - weekly</option>
    <option value="3">3 : £6.00 GBP - weekly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Select your delivery area">Select your delivery area</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
    <option value="Easton">Easton </option>
    <option value="St. Werburghs">St. Werburghs </option>
    <option value="St. Pauls">St. Pauls </option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I've tried to add 'shipping=0.25' into the advanced variables, and tried putting the HTML in, but neither work. I know its possible, as I can go into 'manage subscriptions / shipping' and manually set the delivery price after the subscription has created (which I guess could be our back-up option - Does anyone have any ideas?

Thankyou!

Joshua

I tried to set up a shipping amount on a paypal subscription button, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

There are no [Legacy Payments Standard HTML recurring payment variables](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#link-recurringpaymentvariables) for separate shipping amounts.

Legacy payment standard integrations (including this pill "Subscribe" button) are deprecated and should not be used for new integrations.

Instead, see the current [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) documentation.

A Subscribe button can be created interactively in the PayPal account via https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans

To add shipping to a button, include a `shipping_amount` object in the JSON of its subscription creation, alongside the `plan_id` (the only required parameter). The format of the create subscription payload is documented in the [create subscription API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its such a shame when large tech companies take a step backwards in features. The new subscriptions features *may* be more flexible, but without knowledge of coding, they lack functionality (like custom fields, which are really important to me)

Comment: Yes, some JS knowledge is needed. For additional data use the custom_id field , it can be populated when the button is clicked using `document.getElementById('...').value` or similar